# Conversion of SpriteKit coordinates

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm trying to make my game working on iOS 9 and I faced a problem.
I was using this code to calculate position for a new node and it was working fine in iOS 7 and 8 but now in iOS 9 it isn't working:

```
CGPoint position = [self convertPointFromView:CGPointMake([self convertPointToView:CGPointMake(node.position.x, node.position.y)].x - 30, [self convertPointToView:CGPointMake(node.position.x, node.position.y)].y - 30)];
```

I tried another way but there is the same problem:

```
CGPoint position = [self.view convertPoint:CGPointMake(roundf([self.view convertPoint:CGPointMake(node.position.x, node.position.y) fromScene:self.scene].x + 30), roundf([self.view convertPoint:CGPointMake(node.position.x, node.position.y) fromScene:self.scene].y + 30)) toScene:self.scene];
```

So then I decided to test it with this:

```
NSLog(@"%f", node.position.y);
CGPoint test = [self.view convertPoint:CGPointMake(node.position.x, node.position.y) fromScene:self];
NSLog(@"%f", test.y);
CGPoint test1 = [self.view convertPoint:test toScene:self];
NSLog(@"%f", test1.y);
```

And received this as output:

```
2015-08-06 20:25:57.215 Rendzu[30011:226250] 59.076904
2015-08-06 20:25:57.216 Rendzu[30011:226250] -29.999998
2015-08-06 20:25:57.216 Rendzu[30011:226250] 827.076904
```

Now I think that it's a bug or I just don't understand how it works. Can anybody explain this to me? Thank you for you help and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, I think this is a bug in iOS 9, although a workaround exists. It seems that the differing origin of coordinates isn't accounted for with `convertPoint:fromScene:`

Try this:

```
NSLog(@"%f", node.position.y);
CGPoint test = [self.view convertPoint:CGPointMake(node.position.x,node.position.y) fromScene:self];
NSLog(@"%f", test.y);
CGPoint test1 = [self.view convertPoint:CGPointMake(test.x,test.y + self.view.bounds.size.height) toScene:self];
NSLog(@"%f", test1.y);
```

Here is actually a description of [the problem](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7461)

Hope this helps